# Mounting a remote file system (sshfs) through an intermediate machine

Tags: linux, ssh, filesystems, sshfs, remote-file-inclusion

The situation:

- I am working from **machine1**, where I have root access. From **machine1** I can access **machine2** (where I am a user with no privileges) through ssh.
- **machine3** (also user with no privileges) is not directly accessible from **machine1**. I need to use an ssh connection from **machine2** to access **machine3**.
- In short: **machine1** can ssh into **machine2** but not into **machine3**. **machine2** can ssh into **machine3**.

What I want to do:

- I want to use sshfs to mount on **machine1** a local (own) directory located on **machine3**.

Complications:

- sshfs is not available on **machine2**.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use ssh to forward port 22 from machine3 to machine1 via machine2, like

```
user1@machine1:$ ssh -L 2222:machine3:22 user2@machine2
```

After that configure sshfs on machine1 to use `localhost:2222` port (in the second terminal tab):

```
user1@machine1:$ sshfs user3@localhost:/some/machine3/dir /some/local/dir -p 2222
```

Comment: @Tomek Rękawek: Nice one.

Comment: SSH tunnels. Beauty.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, mount machine 3 on machine 2 via sshfs, then mount the sshfs directory of machine 2 in machine 1.

As no-privilege user, you can only create folders in your home directory.

So theoretically, this should work (but be slow):

machine2:

```
mkdir /home/<username>/sshfs
sshfs <machine3_username>@machine3:/ /home/<username>/sshfs
```

machine1:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sshfs
sshfs <machine2_username>@machine2:/home/<username>/sshfs /mnt/sshfs
```

Comment: I forgot to say sshfs is not available on **machine2**.

Comment: @Miguel: Then Tomek Rękawek's answer should work. You may have to copy id_rsa.pub & private to machine1 and create a user account there, if you use ssh with private-public-keys instead of password.